# Mozilla CORS issue work around

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have the following code in a script on a page:

```
function getJSON(url, passedFunction) {
    console.log("getJSON start: "+url);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    globalForXhr = xhr;
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");  //stop Mozilla bug
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("getJSON ready state change: "+xhr.readyState+" and xhr: "+xhr.status);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            try {
                passedFunction(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Got an exception ("+e+") whille trying to handle: "+url);
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

I have two situations: the page is served by a remote server S1, and the code is calling to another remote server S2.   All the standard CORS headers are in place and this works fine in both Mozilla and Chrome.

But, I am also running TomCat on my local machine L1, and again calling the same remote server S2.  When served from L1 (via http) it works in Chrome but in Mozilla it fails.

First is a call to the local server (which served up the page), and then the second is a call to the global external S2.  The console output in chrome is:

```
getJSON start: http://myserver.local:8080/weaver/auth/
getJSON ready state change: 2 and xhr: 200
getJSON ready state change: 3 and xhr: 200
getJSON ready state change: 4 and xhr: 200
getJSON start: https://external.server.com/eid/?openid.mode=apiWho
getJSON ready state change: 2 and xhr: 200
getJSON ready state change: 3 and xhr: 200
getJSON ready state change: 4 and xhr: 200
```

However, in Mozilla, I am getting a failure only when the page is served from local TomCat server, only when requesting the remote server, and only in Mozilla:

```
"getJSON start: http://myserver.local:8080/weaver/auth/"
getJSON ready state change: 2 and xhr: 200
getJSON ready state change: 3 and xhr: 200
getJSON ready state change: 4 and xhr: 200
"getJSON start: https://external.server.com/eid/?openid.mode=apiWho"
getJSON ready state change: 2 and xhr: 0
getJSON ready state change: 4 and xhr: 0
```

xhr.status is returning zero when the call to the remote (S2) server is called.   There is a lot of discussion on the web about how this status can return zero in all sorts of situations that are very poorly documented at best.  Many of them are decisions by Mozilla to abort the call because cross site scripting paranoia -- and it really does not tell you when it is doing this.

I suspect that serving the page from a local server might be detected by Mozilla, which then aborts the request, and simply fails without telling why.

Does anyone know of any way to confirm the reason that Mozilla is failing to make the request?

I saw some documentation of a way to set Mozilla so that it would go ahead and make the request, but other notes say that was removed in 2015.  I would like to test my site in Mozilla served from a local server.  Does anyone know of a way to turn off this behavior?

## Update

There is no mention in the network tab for this call.   The call to .../weaver/auth is there witha 200 response, but the call to the external server is simply not appearing in the list.  There is no error message that I can find anywhere.  It simply does not make the request.  Very frustrating.

To assure myself this is not a cache issue, I have changed the URL being requested (by adding a dummy query parameter) and the behavior remains the same:  works on Chrome, status=0 on Mozilla.

The external server is https and it has a valid certificate.  This is an identity server and I am using this to authenticate the user -- and obviously the only way to call it is through https.  The mixed http and https is not a problem when the page is served from the other (S1) server which is also http.

I must make the call with credentials because this is a single signon protocol.  If someone is already logged into the identity server, I want them to be immediately authenticated.  That comes from the cookies.  Making the call without credentials would defeat the whole purpose of SSO.  If I remove the 'withCredentials' the page is fetched without issue (but of course authentication of the user is defeated).

The headers from the server includes Access-Control-Max-Age with a value of "1".

## Update 2

Problem was caused by "Privacy Badger" which attempt to block calls that are made for tracking purposes.  It blocks the calls, but makes no entry in the console.  It also prevents the attempt at fetching a page from appearing in the network panel.

I am not sure why Privacy Badger behaved differently for sites hosted in different places.  I might be that as some point in the past I 'approved' access to that site from this site, and it remembered that.  But other sites do not have that registered, and so are blocked.

**Lesson Learned:  Disable ALL plugins when you start having browser problems**

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of the Firefox Developer Tools for the request that is failing? Is it a preflight OPTIONS request that is failing or the GET request itself?

Comment: On your second request, your using `https` but on your first request your using `http`..  I know in Chrome it sometimes complains about mixing `http` & `https`, so I wonder if it's related to mixing protocols.  Also does, `https://external.server.com/eid/?openid.mode=apiWho` have a valid certificate?.

Comment: Caching maybe? Perhaps it's using an older version of your JS? Or maybe the CORS response is cached from when you tried it earlier in development and that's why you don't even see the request going out. Maybe try running off your IP address rather than `localhost`, or vice versa, just so the origin server changes and encourages caches to be ignored.

Comment: Does the remote server set an `Access-Control-Max-Age` header? If it is a preflight caching problem then that'll be a hint. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age